# Prove this set equality: $(S_1 \cup S_2) - S_1 = S_2 - S_1$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble figuring out this problem. I have looked online for some identities and I have found one identity that has gotten me on my first step, but it hasn't helped me that much at all.

$(S_1 \cup S_2) - S_1 = S_2 - S_1$ (Original)

$(S_1 \cup S_2) - S_1 = S_2 \cap S_1 '$

I don't know where to go from here. I have looked online for other identities and still don't know where to go from here.

Comment: What is $S_1'$?

Comment: @RafaelHolanda Compliment of $S_1$

Answer (score 1):

$(S_1 \cup S_2)- S_1=(S_1 \cup S_2)\cap S_1'=(S_1 \cap S_1') \cup (S_2\cap S_1')=\phi \cup (S_2 -S_1)=S_2-S_1$

Answer (score 0):

First identity: if $x\in(S_1 \cup S_2)-S_1$, i.e., $x\in(S_1 \cup S_2)$ and $x\notin S_1$, then $x\in S_2$ and $x\notin S_1$, hence $x\in S_2-S_1$. For other hand, if $y\in S_2-S_1$, then $y\in S_2\subseteq S_1 \cup S_2$ and $y\notin S_1$; therefore $y\in(S_1 \cup S_2)-S_1$.

Second identity: note that $S_2-S_1=\{x\in S_2:x\notin S_1\}=\{x\in S_2:x\in S_1'\}=S_2\cap S_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same trick you used to go from wanting to show $(S_1 \cup S_2) - S_1 = S_2 - S_1$ to wanting to show
$(S_1 \cup S_2) - S_1 = S_2 \cap S_1'$, we can note that
$$
(S_1 \cup S_2) - S_1 = (S_1 \cup S_2) \cap S_1',
$$
so you want to show:
$$
S_2 \cap S_1' = (S_1 \cup S_2) \cap S_1'.
$$

At this point, simply the right hand side using the distributive rule, $(A \cup B) \cap C = (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)$. See if you can solve it using that.

Comment: How do you go from $S_2 \cap S_1'$ to $S_1 \cup S_2 \cap S_1'$? Is that an identity that I just don't know?

Comment: No, that's what we want to show. Remember one side of the equation you want to show is $S_2 - S_1 = S_1 \cap S_1'$, and the other side is $(S_1 \cup S_2) - S_1 =(S_1 \cup S_2) \cap S_1'$. Anything in my answer prefaced by "you want to show" is just that -- something we are trying to show in order to answer the problem, not something that is clearly true.